# configure email for sql job

Tags: sql, sql-server, jobs

I am creating an sql job with a series of stored procedures. These procedures can result in errors or failures. 
What I want to do is to be able to send an email each time an error occurs.
My problem is that I'm not sure how to configure this in a way that can be configured and shipped to client. 
I have followed this tutorial: [set up email for sql server express](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/querying-microsoft-sql-server/2013/09/02/sending-mail-using-sql-server-express-edition/)

what is the best way to configure emailing for job sql that can be shipped and configured by clients.

Comment: I will tell you from experience that this is a bad way to handle errors. You end up inundated with error messages. Two (better) options to consider. Simply logging to a standard text file and watching that log or logging to a SQL server database table. And if an email is still desired sending an email once a day if there is content to look at.

Comment: @Tanner: thanks for your response, but the links you have provided are not a solution for sql server express as you can't set up the email functionality from the interface.

Comment: @FrankV: thanks for your response, the thing is that the errors in this program are very critical and need to be notified right away

Answer (score 0):

I never tested it using SQL Express, but using SQL 2008 R2 Standard I use the sp_send_dbmail like so:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'Default',
    @recipients = 'email@example.com',
    @query = '


    SELECT * FROM table

    ' ,
    @subject = 'Email subject',
    @attach_query_result_as_file = 0
```

This is in a subtask from on of one my maintenance plans. This subtask is executed only when the parent task fails.

[image]

In order for that to work, you'll have to set the mail profile first as explain in the link you attached to your post.

Comment: thanks Julian, what you have described is similar to what I'm doing. I have already set up the email profile in the system database on the sql server.
But I don't quite understand how that would be shipped to client on their own server? should I write another stored procedure as part of my sql job which will set up the profile and sender email account so that the correct settings will be made on the client's sql server? my question might be trivial but I'm still a newbie with stored procedure and mailing..